# Sports Stack Exchange Google+ Fan Page

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I would like to start a Google+ fan page of the Sports beta site.

Primary goal could be:

1. circle active users
2. circle people who have answered/posted questions (users tab, new users)
3. Make an inventory of communities (sports related).
4. Post questions/answers to those communities/circles

I've been managing the fan page of [Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2425/29140), single handedly, for a couple of months now, and it's been an easy job thus far.

The ultimate achievement would be to create more momentum for the Sports beta site.

Comment: Nice idea! People who love sports will find our website by the fan page on Google+. And we can get some more attention/visits on our website. +1

Comment: @hims056 are you interested in managing as well?

Comment: Hi @Jacob I will support and spread the fan page but won't able to manage it. :(

Comment: Still no word about a google+ page for Sports SE. Stay tuned.

Comment: +1, I'll support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked, we listened.

Sports SE is now a Google+ Fan Page: [Sports Stack Exchange - Google+](http://plus.google.com/u/0/b/114887802783150921199/114887802783150921199/posts)

If anyone is interested in managing the page, please feel free to volunteer.

Comment: I would like to co-manage the Google+ page !!

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Sent you an invite to be a manager. Any interest in owning, or would that be too much for you?